# assertionerror with python3 and virtualenv

Tags: python-3.x, installation, virtualenv, ubuntu-10.04

In ubuntu lucid,I have `python2.6` by default.I wanted to install `python 3.3.1`.

I extracted  from `Python-3.3.1.tar.bz2` into my home folder sothat `/home/me/Python-3.3.1` contains all the files.Then as per the Readme I did

```
./configure
make
make test
sudo make install
```

This created an executable named `python` in `/home/me/Python-3.3.1` folder.

Also, nowI have several `python3*` files in the `/usr/local/bin` directory.

Among them ,

python3 is a link to executable,

python3.3 is an executable,

python3.3m is an executable.

I wanted to create a virtualenv for python3 and tried the following

```
sudo virtualenv envpy331 --distribute --no-site-packages --python=/home/me/Python-3.3.1/python
```

This produced an AssertionError

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/virtualenv-1.8.2-py2.6.egg/virtualenv.py", line 2471, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/virtualenv-1.8.2-py2.6.egg/virtualenv.py", line 942, in main
    never_download=options.never_download)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/virtualenv-1.8.2-py2.6.egg/virtualenv.py", line 1043, in create_environment
    site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/virtualenv-1.8.2-py2.6.egg/virtualenv.py", line 1207, in install_python
    copy_required_modules(home_dir)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/virtualenv-1.8.2-py2.6.egg/virtualenv.py", line 1159, in copy_required_modules
    dst_filename = change_prefix(filename, dst_prefix)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/virtualenv-1.8.2-py2.6.egg/virtualenv.py", line 1134, in change_prefix
    (filename, prefixes)
AssertionError: Filename /home/me/Python-3.3.1/Lib/os.py does not start with any of these prefixes: ['/usr/local']
```

what do I need to correct this? do I need to remove the python3 installation ,or do I need to reconfigure it with `prefix=/usr/local` ? and again run the install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already installed it. Just point to the installed python3.
try this:

```
virtualenv envpy331 --python=/usr/local/bin/python3.3
```