# Python3 and Virtualenv setting error in mac with anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, anaconda, python-venv

I am trying to create virtualenv that would use python3 ie I am doing the following:

```
$python3 -m venv .env
```

as explained in [cs231n Stanford](http://cs231n.github.io/assignments2017/assignment3/)

But no matter what I do, I am always getting the following error:
`Error: Command '['/Users/hmi/Documents/spring2017/cs231n/assignment/assignment3/.env/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.`

For the record, I am using Macbook, OSX El Capitan, and

`$which python
/Users/hmi/anaconda3/bin/python`

I tried pretty much all the things suggested in different stackoverflow posts. For instance:

1. From [assertionerror with python3 and virtualenv

][1](http://cs231n.github.io/assignments2017/assignment3/)

[1](http://cs231n.github.io/assignments2017/assignment3/): [assertionerror with python3 and virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098830/assertionerror-with-python3-and-virtualenv) I did this:

`virtualenv envypy331 --python=/Users/hmi/anaconda3/bin/python3`

But none seem to work. But when I did this:
`virtualenv -p python3 .env`

What's going on here actually? I am getting totally lost with similar issue each time I try to do same thing.

Comment: Why are you using virtualenv with Anaconda? Why not use conda environments?

Comment: I use `virtualenv -p python3 name_of_env` to create a Python 3.x virtualenv, but I don't use Anaconda.